# Is there any benefit in restricting a numeric field in Postgres? E.g.: numeric(70,0) instead of numeric

Tags: postgresql, numeric

I'm working with large integer numbers, which I currently represent in PG using `numeric(x, 0)`. I don't want to think about `x` each time, so I'm wondering:

Is there any benefit (storage, performance, etc.) to use `numeric(x, 0)` instead of just the generic `numeric`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constrained `numeric(x,0)` is used to ensure that numbers are rounded to one, regardless of the format in which they are entered.

```sql
select 1.8::numeric(50,0)

 numeric
---------
       2
(1 row)
```

When it comes to performance, the difference between the use of constrained and unconstrained numerics is negligible.

Comment: Check. Since I already guarantee that upstream, there doesn't seem to be a good reason left not to use unbounded numeric

Comment: Yes, there are no performance or storage related reasons to use bounded numerics.